# Add upload field from code at new product form - Magento 2.1

Tags: adminhtml, product-attribute, magento-2.1

I'm developing an extension that adds an additional upload field to the product edit form. In Magento 2.0.x I could just simple add an input and the file would be added to the post. Now, with Magento 2.1, the field is not added anymore in the post after saving a product.

Did this change since Magento 2.1? How should I add a custom field to a my custom product tab?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? Having the same problem...